# How to reply from outside of the hapi.js route handler

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have a [hapi.js](http://hapijs.com/) route where I want to defer the response.  I've tried storing the `reply` function and calling it later, or wrapping it in a promise, but hapi always responds immediately with a 500 Internal Server Error response.

Store the reply for later:

```
var pendingReplies = {};
server.route({
    method: "POST",
    path: "/",
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        var id = generateId();
        pendingReplies[id] = reply;
    }
});
... // reply later by calling:
function sendResponse(id, data) {
    pendingReplies[id](data);
}
```

I've tried creating a promise to reply:

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
    var id = generateId();
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pendingReplies[id] = resolve;
    }).then(function (data) {
        return reply(data);
    });
}
```

I've tried using [`reply().hold()`](http://hapijs.com/api#flow-control)

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
    var id = generateId();
    var response = reply().hold();
    pendingReplies[id] = function (data) {
        response.source = data;
        response.send();
    };
    return response;
}
```

I've tried using `reply().hold()` with a Promise:

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
    var id = generateId();
    var response = reply().hold();
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        pendingReplies[id] = resolve;
    }).then(function (data) {
        response.source = data;
        response.send();
        return response;
    });
}
```

With each of these, as soon as the handler function exits, I get a 500 response and the following output in the node console:

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    Error: Uncaught error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:198:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:283:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:163:7)
    at _stream_readable.js:891:16
    at process._tickDomainCallback (node.js:388:13)
```

Is it possible with hapi to reply to a request asynchronously from outside of the route handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an error is thrown within your handler, `hapi.js` will immediately exit and give a `500` status code. Check if `generateId()` is a valid function.

The rest of your code looks right for your third and fourth examples. `reply().hold()` is necessary to keep the connection open after `handler` returns.

Comment: Yes, `generateId()` is just a uuid generator.  It works.  I can step through the code in the debugger and verify that the handler exits without errors.  Actually, there is an error in the node console that I forgot to share.  I'll update my question with the output when I get back to my computer.

Comment: The reason I was able to step through the handler and "verify" there was no error is because the error was thrown by another asynchronous call (that I excluded from my question).  Once I fixed that, everything worked, using my third example, as you suggested.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the version 8, Hapi supports Promised responses, so you can do :

```
var respond = function(message) {
    return new Bluebird.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(message);
        }, 2000);
    });
};

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {
        reply(respond("Hello buddy"));
    }
});
```