# How to return Hapi reply with promise and vo.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, hapi.js, nightmare

I have an asynchronous nightmare.js process which uses [vo.js](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/vo) flow control with a generator:

```
vo(function *(url) {
  return yield request.get(url);
})('http://lapwinglabs.com', function(err, res) {
  // ... 
})
```

This needs to return a promise to Hapi (v.13.0.0) with `reply()` interface. I have seen examples with Bluebird and other promise libraries, eg: [How to reply from outside of the hapi.js route handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402797/how-to-reply-from-outside-of-the-hapi-js-route-handler), but having trouble adapting vo.js. Could someone please provide an example of this?

**server.js**

```
server.route({
method: 'GET',
path:'/overview', 
handler: function (request, reply) {
    let crawl = scrape.doCrawl({"user": USERNAME, "pass": PASSWORD});
    reply( ... ).code( 200 );
    }
});
```

**scrape.js**

```
module.exports = {
    DoCrawl: function(credentials) { 
        var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
        var vo = require('vo');

        vo(function *(credentials) {
            var nightmare = Nightmare();
            var result = yield nightmare
               .goto("www.example.com/login")       
               ...
            yield nightmare.end();
            return result

        })(credentials, function(err, res) {
              if (err) return console.log(err);
              return res
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: Can't you create a new promise and wrap return value in this, you could then call reply with resolved value?!  Not very good with promises but I have seen others use this method when returning promises from hapi's reply callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to send the result of `doCrawl` to hapi's `reply` method, you'll have to convert `doCrawl` to return a promise. Something like this (untested):

**server.js**

```
server.route({
method: 'GET',
path:'/overview', 
handler: function (request, reply) {
    let crawl = scrape.doCrawl({"user": USERNAME, "pass": PASSWORD});
    // crawl is a promise
    reply(crawl).code( 200 );
    }
});
```

**scrape.js**

```
module.exports = {
    doCrawl: function(credentials) { 
        var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
        var vo = require('vo');

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            vo(function *(credentials) {
                var nightmare = Nightmare();
                var result = yield nightmare
                   .goto("www.example.com/login")       
                   ...
                yield nightmare.end();
                return result

            })(credentials, function(err, res) {
                // reject the promise if there is an error
                if (err) return reject(err);
                // resolve the promise if successful
                resolve(res);
            })
        })
    }
};
```